# C++11 - How to provide a valid constructor for rvalue references to multidimensional arrays?

Tags: c++11, multidimensional-array, matrix, constructor

When implementing a `Matrix4`-class template (*represents a 4 by 4 matrix*), I ran into a problem with constructors in this class. I tried to declare valid constructors for multidimensional arrays (*well, in this case, two-dimensional arrays aka matrices*), but failed to do so. Here are my constructors for both lvalue and rvalue references to multidimensional arrays:

```
Matrix4(T (&matrix_)[4][4]);
Matrix4(T (&&matrix_)[4][4]);
```

Both of these declarations seem to be acceptable, but invoking the constructor taking rvalue reference does not work as expected:

```
// Works:
float matrix__[4][4] = {{0}};
Matrix4<float> matrix1__ = matrix__;

// Does not work:
Matrix4<float> matrix2__ = {
    {0, 0, 7, 0},
    {1, 0, 5, 0},
    {0, 0, 4, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 2}
};
```

From the piece of code that does not work, I get the following error:

> error: could not convert '{{0, 0, 7, 0}, {1, 0, 5, 0}, {0, 0, 4, 0},
>   {0, 0, 0, 2}}' from '' to
>   'Matrix4'

So, how to provide a valid constructor for rvalue references to multidimensional arrays?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because of a class has no initializer-list constructor, a `{ a, b, c }` initializer is treated as calling the set of constructors with three arguments, `a`, `b` and `c`. So to make your example work, slap in another `{ ... }` that accounts for this peeling-off of the outer-most braces

```
Matrix4<float> matrix2__ = {{
    {0, 0, 7, 0},
    {1, 0, 5, 0},
    {0, 0, 4, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 2}
}};
```

Comment: Well, that seemed to do the trick. Thanks a lot! I just sometimes hate how C++11 compilers seem to prefer brace-enclosed initializer lists over traditional array initialization lists. Better get used to syntax like this. Still better than Matrix4<float> matrix2__ = { .data {...}}; :/